# How to bind IPV6 socket to interface(ethernet) in Windows using scope_id?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, ipv6, ethernet

I tried to bind IPV6 socket in windows, here bind is successful. But I want to bind it to particular interface (like ethernet0 or ethernet1). I tried to use functions like *if_nametoindex()* and *if_indextoname()* but in this case I don't know that how to find scope_id of particular interface, so that I can use like this here *server6.sin6_scope_id = ?*. I have done this code in Linux and it works fine. But for Windows OS how to find all interfaces which are connected so that I can use this interface name in function *if_nametoindex()* to get the scope_id in Windows OS and then bind it ??? ( Problem with windows is that it is providing name like ethernet_0, ethernet_4, tunnel_0 by using *if_indextoname()* function, so how to determine that which interface is LAN connected or not, so what should I add to this following code so I can bind it to particular interface.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <netioapi.h> 
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    int wsaerr;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char buffer[1024];
    int k, i = 0, p, scope_id;
    int off = 0;
    char * interface_name = NULL;
    SOCKET sockfd;
    char * addr = "fe80::38d4:2862:404b:f781"; 
    struct sockaddr_in6 server6;
    printf("\n Ready for Receiving...\n");
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 

    if(sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
       printf("\n Error.... ");    
    else
       printf("\n Successful Creation....\n");

       memset(&server6, 0, sizeof (server6));
       server6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
       server6.sin6_port = htons(5000);
       server6.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
       p = inet_pton(AF_INET6, addr, &server6.sin6_addr);
       setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_IPV6,IPV6_V6ONLY,(char *)&off, sizeof(off));

       if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server6 , sizeof(server6))==-1)
       {
            printf("\n Error in binding..\n");       
       }
       else{
            printf("\n Binding successful...\n");
       }
       k = sizeof(server6);

       recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server6, &k);     
       printf("\n Message from client %s: ", buffer);

       strcpy(buffer,"Hi This is Client...");
       sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server6,k);
       closesocket(sockfd);
       getch();
       return 0;
}
```